# Android: Video recording on virtual device. Is it possible?

Tags: android, camera, video-recording

I have simple question.

I am developing an application that can record video capture. The application is working successfully on a hardware device, but it is not on a virtual device.

the error: *"can't connect camera"*

I guess so, a video recording can not working on a virtual device. am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I have had video working in [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) in the past, but I don't know if I ever got it working with the standard emulator.

Comment: Not really.  It's proprietary C/C++ code and way too much code to pluck out samples.